# In Androidviewclient(version 3.2.0), Is there any api to get unique id for text

Tags: monkeyrunner, androidviewclient

I am new to automation in androidviewclient. Please help me by answering following queries:

1. In Androidviewclient(version 3.2.0), Is there any api to get unique id for text.
2. Is there any documentation available for AndroidViewClient (3.2.0 version). I tried searching on net, but getting only examples.

Comment: What would be the reason to use 3.2.0 and not the latest one?

Comment: We have already automated certain test cases with monkey-runner and since it works with coordinates bases. We are trying to re-use our script with minimal changes.I was able to solve my problem by using getId() function

Comment: What do you really mean by "*get unique id for text*"?

Comment: I used command: view=vc.findViewWithText(text).getId()